# Iterating through a list of lists (without flattening)

Tags: list, prolog, iteration

I have the following list of lists:

```
listObj = [ [ obj1(_) , obj2(_) , obj1(_) , obj2(_) , obj1(_) , obj2(_) ],
            [ obj3    , obj3    , obj2(_) , obj1(_) , obj1(_) , obj2(_) ],
            [ obj1(_) , obj2(_) , obj1(_) , obj2(_) , obj1(_) , obj2(_) ],
            [ obj1(_) , obj2(_) , obj1(_) , obj2(_) , obj1(_) , obj2(_) ],
            [ obj1(_) , obj2(_) , obj1(_) , obj2(_) , obj1(_) , obj2(_) ],
            [ obj1(_) , obj2(_) , obj1(_) , obj2(_) , obj1(_) , obj2(_) ]
          ]
```

This list will always be a 6x6 matrix, and I need to iterate through this list in a way that I can retain the row and column number of each element I pass through (for use in another clause which I will be calling in the loop). From my understanding, I can't just use flatten/2, as this wouldn't help me retain the row and column number.

P.S. On another note, how can I access the value of a CLP variable in order to set up a constraint. For instance, x can have the value 0 or 1, y has a value > x. Would the constraint just be
    y #>= x

Comment: can't you use numpy and vectorize?

Comment: The example list you are showing doesn't seem to look like it's part of a 6x6 matrix. I see a row of 3 and a row of 4. Also, I don't see a question anywhere regarding the list of lists.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question. Isn't the listObj a list of lists? Each element itself is a list holding 6 objects.

Comment: Does `obj3` really have no arguments, whereas `obj1` and `obj2` each have one? I'm still a little confused regarding exactly what you want a query to do. Could you give an example of what you want for a query and results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SWI prolog, you can say (using zero-relative indices):

```
:- use_module( library(lists) ).

array_cell(Xs,R,C,E) :-
  nth0(R,Xs,Rs) ,
  nth0(C,Rs,E)
  .
```

Or you can roll your own, something like this:

```
cell_at( Xs , R , C , X ) :-
  element_at( Xs  , 0 , R , Row ) ,
  element_at( Row , 0 , C , X )
  .

element_at( [X|Xs] , N , N , X ) .
element_at( [_|Xs] , N , I , X ) :-
  N1 is N+1 ,
  element_at( Xs , N1 , I , X )
  .
```

Or...

```
cell_at( List , R , C , Cell ) :-
  cell_at( List , 0 , 0 , R , C , Cell ) .

cell_at( [ [Y|Ys] | Xs ] , R , C , R , C , Y )    % success! Return the current cell and its grid coordinates via unification
  .
cell_at( [ [_|Ys] | Xs ] , I , J , R , C , Y ) :- % on backtracking, if the current row is not yet exhausted,
  J1 is J+1 ,                                     % - increment the column index
  cell_at( [Ys|Xs] , I , J1 , R , C , Y )         % - and recurse down
  .                                               %
cell_at( [ []     | Xs ] , I , J , R , C , Y ) :- % on backtracking, if the current row is exhausted,
  I1 is I+1 ,                                     % - increment the row index
  cell_at( Xs , I1 , 0 , R , C , Y )              % - and recurse down, resetting the column index to zero.
  .                                               % Easy!
```

**Extra Credit:** modify the above to enumerate the 2-D "array" in column major order.